# Shutting down a socket without socket.shutdown

Tags: sockets, lua

I'm programming an FTP client with a special lua interpreter. The problem is that I need to shut down a socket, but my library does not include that option (it includes Socket.connect, Socket.send, Socket.receive, but not Socket.shutdown) and I can't edit it.

The question is: is there any way I can replicate socket.shutdown with only these three commands?

Comment: "but my library does not include that option" What library? Most socket libraries have a 'close()' function that you can pass an errorcode/closereason to.

Comment: as an FTP client you should be able to send the 'QUIT' command, then the ftp server will take care of closing the connection/disconnecting your socket

Comment: I'm using a very limited lua library for the 3ds (https://rinnegatamante.it/lpp-3ds_doc.html). The close function doesn't have a close reason argument. I can use quit, but that disconnects the ftp client entirely, and doesn't let me transfer more files afterwards

Comment: Really confused on what you want then. If you shutdown the socket then yes you would be disconnected and need to reconnect. What do you want otherwise when you say shutdown in the question?

Comment: I just want to shut down the data socket used for the transfer. Using quit would disconnect all sockets